# Having issue about javascript arrays and objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to save book objects in an array,
but the issue is I am unable to get the value from a user that how many books he wants to add, I want you guys to focus on the loop `for(var i=0 ;i<2;i++)`. I want this loop to run by the number provided by the user. Let's say if a user enters 3 the code should be able to add three books, and before adding a new object it must show a message that enter a new book and then comes the property of an object to be entered

```
function addbook() {
  let library = [];

  function book(title, author, page, red) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.page = page;
    this.red = red;

    this.bookinfo = function() {
      return "Author: " + this.author + "\nTitle: " + this.title + "\nPages: " + this.page + "\nRed: " + this.red;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    book[i] = new book(window.prompt("Enter title"),
      window.prompt("Enter Author"),
      window.prompt("Enter pages"),
      window.prompt("Have you red it yet"));
    library.push(book[i].bookinfo());
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < library.length; i++) {
    console.log(library[i]);
    console.log(library.indexOf(library[i]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Using prompt this way gives a very, very bad user experience. I could answer, but I won't as this is just a horrible pattern. Consider a different, user-friendly way of input, where user can go back to any previous input, make corrections, verify their input at their own convenience, etc.

Comment: Because nobody here is obligated to help you. What trincot is saying is "you are basically hitting your thumb with a hammer and it's pointless to help you until you decide to stop hitting your thumb".

Comment: Guys, chill. What if the OP is just practicing JavaScript and not building a production app? Maybe he is learning how to use constructor functions with *some* user input or just want to learn the language or get used to it? We don't know the story behind the question. We should focus more on the answer and not on the question until we don't know the bigger picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are trying to achieve?

You simply need to parametrize the `addbook()` function and ask a user to provide the number of books to be added. Also, an `alert()` in the first loop will show the book number you are adding.

```js
function addbook(amount) {
  let library = [];

  function book(title, author, page, red) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.page = page;
    this.red = red;

    this.bookinfo = function() {
      return "Author: " + this.author + "\nTitle: " + this.title + "\nPages: " + this.page + "\nRed: " + this.red;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    alert("Book #" + (i+1));
    var b = new book(window.prompt("Enter title"),
      window.prompt("Enter Author"),
      window.prompt("Enter pages"),
      window.prompt("Have you red it yet"));
    library.push(b.bookinfo());
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < library.length; i++) {
    console.log(library[i]);
    console.log(library.indexOf(library[i]));
  }
}

addbook(+window.prompt("How many books?"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following function.
It will loop as long as no valid integer was entered and prompt the user to enter a something.

```
function promptInt(title, defaultVal) {
  while (true) {
    let input = window.prompt(title, defaultVal.toString());
    let amount = parseInt(input);

    if (!isFinite(bookAmount) || bookAmount <= 0) {
      console.log('Please enter a valid number!');
    } else {
      return amount;
    }
  }
}
```

And then later in your code:

```
const bookAmount = promptInt('How many books do you wanna add?', '1');

for (int i = 0; i < bookAmount; i++) {
  const prefix = "[Book " + (i + 1) + "] ";
  book[i] = new book(
    window.prompt(prefix + "Enter a title"),
    window.prompt(prefix + "Enter the author"),
    window.prompt(prefix + "Enter the page amount"),
    window.prompt(prefix + "Have you red it yet")
  );
  library.push(book[i].bookinfo());
}
```